# How to plot the phase portrait of this system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

I want to plot the phase portrait
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
{x'=y^{2}-x^{2}} \\
{y'=2xy}
\end{array}\right.$$
I have solved $y(3x^{2}-y^{2})=constant$, but I don't know how to sketch the phase portrait.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, many thanks!!!

Comment: Did you notice that $(x+iy)^2=x^2-y^2+i 2xy$? So you can solve $z'=z^2$ explicitly and then change a sign to sketch the phase portrait.

Comment: Wow, it's a nice way to look at the question, but  $z'=x'+iy'=y^{2}-x^{2}+i2xy=(y+ix)^{2}$.

Comment: "and then change a sign"